# Creating generic Achivement System for User activities

Tags: language-agnostic

I want to create a generic web based achievement system for the User activities

example
If user play 2 sports football and Running

4 possible achievements could be

1. List item
2. Score 3 Goals in 1 Game of football
3. Run 10 Km in 45 minutes
4. Run in rain and burn 200 calories
5. Score 5 Goals in 1 Game

now these four achievements could be achieve on only football because user also do running in football or user can achieve these  achievements by the combination of Both Football and Running

the parameters we have to consider in calculating the achievements are as follow

1. Sessions
2. Time
3. Distance
4. Weather
5. Calories

there could be other parameters

now the scenario is by completing 1 achievement user could also cover other achievement as well 
e.g by scoring 5 goals in a game of football the user unlock achievement 4 but also on same time the user also should unlock achievement 1 that says 3 goals in 1 game.

how can i create this kind of generic achievement system?? what will be the database structure ? what could be the businesslayer of this kind of system.????

i will be very thankful for the community if you help me out to solve this riddle

Regards

Adnan

Answer (score 1):

Generic achievement systems are difficult to build. But I can't say that without being biased though. My company offers a game mechanics platform and api. http://www.iactionable.com